# Term for people who don't joke at all

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

*Joker* is the term that describes people who joke. Are there any terms to describe the opposite of *joker*?

Comment: Someone who never makes jokes or laughs could be called [deadpan](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deadpan)

Comment: A nerd........?

Comment: @Terry LiYifeng: I doubt that. In my understanding, *nerds* are often quite giggly (perhaps because they're often socially awkward).

Comment: You could always go with "Finn".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *deadpan*'s not quite right, there are many, many comedians and comedy actors whose delivery of jokes is deadpan.

Comment: @Mahnax I didn't know people from Finland never joke about anything.

Comment: @Hugo: Stand-up comics have to work hard at deadpan delivery. You won't often find people telling jokes in the pub/office like that - it's very unnatural, which we find even funnier. Comics often joke about death, for example, but that doesn't make death funny.

Comment: @Kris Not *never*, but they are very, very serious people when not drunk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A formal adjective is

> humorless

Some informal nouns are

> stick-in-the-mud
>
> kill-joy
>
> buzz-kill

I can't think of any formal nouns or informal adjectives.

Comment: A killjoy is a person who is anti-fun, or prevents others from having fun. Yeah, 'killjoy' look quite close but then would a Joker allows others to have fun? (Some joker's jokes also make people angry too). Would 'Anti-Joker' be worth considering?

Comment: +1 for *humorless*, which seems the only word coming closest.

Comment: Yes, *humourless* seems perfect. The others confuse the ideas of 'not making jokes' and 'stopping others making jokes'.

Answer (score 6):

Some words that come to mind are sober, serious, and stoic.

Comment: stoic - A person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining. I wish to use the word 'stoic' but if I use it, then 'Joker' might have a new meaning - a person who cannot endure pain or hardship by showing their feelings or complaining?

Comment: Stoic does not mean the opposite of a joker; don't use it thus.

Comment: I agree. Stoic was a reach that slipped away from humorless.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go the metaphorical route, there's "machine," "robot," and such like. Of course the meaning changes depending on context, but still, it's an option.

The mechanical metaphor sort of implies a general lack of emotion, though, in which case "Vulcan" might be more obvious for some people.

Another slangy sort of option would be "stiff." In my experience it doesn't imply anything other than being unnecessarily formal, tense, no fun at all, which to me means not joking around and having fun with everyone else. Still not a perfect match, though. In certain circles being a "stiff" also implies being dead. You might want to keep that in mind just in case.

Comment: stiff is good but the problem is that can I say that people who don't joke at all are called stiff?

Comment: @Larry: I think you could say that, yes. NOAD lists, among several other definitions for _stiff_, "a boring, conventional person."

Answer (score 1):

Some synonyms of already-suggested *killjoy* are *grouch,
spoilsport*, and *wet blanket*.  However, I'd look for synonyms of *[strait-laced](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strait-laced)*, "Having narrow views on moral matters; prudish."  (*[Prudish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prudish)*: "of excessive propriety; easily offended or shocked...") [Synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=prudish&send=Look+it+up) of the latter include  *demure, priggish, prim, prissy, puritanical, square-toed, squeamish, straightlaced, straitlaced, tight-laced*.  Going for [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=deadpan&send=Look+it+up) of recently-suggested *deadpan* gives *impassive, poker-faced, unexpressive*.

*Edit:* Prompted by Larry Morries comment on *non-jokers* I looked up some uses of it.  It isn't a common term (fewer than 3000 Google hits) but in a half-dozen pages I looked at was consistently used specifically to contrast people who joke with people who don't.  Example: [1898 J. F. Muirhead book](http://books.google.com/books?id=lhwEAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=%22non-jokers%22&source=bl&ots=2etI-EZqZZ&sig=gmUcbFN-7i-LrNZUS8tr-qc1oKc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ejzwTseOJM3MiQKNztXFDg&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=%22non-jokers%22&f=false), page 139.

Comment: @JasperLoy - No, I think you're wrong about that, word request answers ideally are meant to be perfect matches.  I agree that *strait-laced* is not exactly what's being asked for here, but none of the suggestions so far have meanings that specifically refer to "non-jokers" and it's worth considering.  Have you ever seen any priggish, prim, prissy, or straitlaced people making jokes?

Comment: I am pretty puritanical, and I shall have you know that I love slapstick and puns. Seriously. I drive people crazy with some of the weird/dumb stuff I come up with. Also: animal noises are always funny. So, I have to say I think your intuition is not too reliable in this case. :)

Comment: @jwpat7, seems like your "non-jokers" is worth considering. Other words are good but they are not closer to "non-jokers" but unless there is a term that is the equivalent of "non-jokers", I think I will have to settle for "non-jokers". (unless you want me to call this group of people - "batman"???)

Comment: @LarryMorries - I added a paragraph about "non-jokers".

Comment: @jwpat7 - thanks for researching on the term "non-jokers". (If there are no better answer than non-jokers. I will vote your answer as correct)

Answer (score 1):

How about uptight? Has someone considered this to be an apt word for people who hate jokes. I tried searching for a word after I called somebody a snob for hating jokes and landed up here.

Answer (score 1):

> [**Agelastic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agelastic)
>
> *rare*
>
> Literary. Never laughing; morose, laughter-hating.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

The term used to be obsolete but has been upgraded to "rare" by the OED.

See [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-age1.htm) for an interesting discussion on the term.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to EL&U. Great word! I've taken the liberty of editing your answer slightly to improve its readability, but if you have the time, I recommend you [edit] it further to add some of the more interesting bits from the WWW discussion :-)